# Access a value from a multidimensional Array to display in HTML table using foreach/for loop

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

Im trying to display each set of Array(first dimension) on a table. There will be a lot of array and table to be created in each page load, that's why I thought of using foreach. The array returned is from the controller.

My returned array looks like this:

Array: $appreq

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Lot Survey Plans and Specifications
                    [Document] => -
                    [Id] => 10
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Others (Specify)
                    [Document] => -
                    [Id] => 11
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Fire Protection Plan (if applicable)
                    [Document] => 
                    [Id] => 12
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Vicinity Map or Location Plan within a Two(2) Kilometer Radius
                    [Document] => -
                    [Id] => 13
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Site Development Plan
                    [Document] => assets/uploads/ca060d9b-93d2-4fcd-8a8b-113bfac8dbbf/Architectural Permit/Site Development Plan...hollow-knight.jpg
                    [Id] => 14
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Perspective
                    [Document] => -
                    [Id] => 15
                    [Is_Received] => 0
                    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
                )
```

Array: $ancillarypermit

[image]

The table should be displaying the data as divided in the first D array, then the rows is the next dimension of the array and my td should contain the: Name and Is_Received value. Please dont mind the table titles(Local Clearance etc), its part of another foreach loop, Im having trouble just with the tbody.

From the array: $appreq

the first dimensional: [0] => Array is the Local Clearance table

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sf1h.png) => Array is the Fire Safety table

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgzBo.png) => Array is the Architectural Permit table

> EXPECTED TABLE:

[image: table1]

There must be something wrong with how I used my foreach variables, and how I call the array to show in the . I really hope someone can help me through this, thanks in advance

UPDATE --------------

I tried doing the following as suggested:

```
<?php foreach($ancillarypermit as $row => $data) : 
     foreach($appreq as $row => $value) : ?>

    <table style="text-align: left; width: 50%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th width='10' style="text-align:center;">Received</th>
            <th scope="col">Requirement</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <h5><strong><?= $data->permit->Name ?></strong></h5>
        <?php 
            foreach ($value as $key => $values) :
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td width='150' style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 3px'>
                        <?php 
                        echo CheckboxX::widget([
                            'name'=>'s_1', 
                            'value'=>$values['Is_Received'], 
                            // 'readonly'=>true, 
                            'pluginOptions'=>['threeState'=>false]
                        ]);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?= $values['Name']  ?> </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; 
endforeach;?>
```

but im getting this result:
[image]

Comment: can you please add expected html table to be displayed.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Hi, I updated my question and added an image, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is, you are looping the array twice, thus going 2 times in.
On the first iteration `$data` would be

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Name] => Lot Survey Plans and Specifications
        [Document] => -
        [Id] => 10
        [Is_Received] => 0
        [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [Name] => Others (Specify)
        [Document] => -
        [Id] => 11
        [Is_Received] => 0
        [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
    )
)
```

On the first iteration of the 2nd foreach, `$values` would be

```
Array(
    [Name] => Lot Survey Plans and Specifications
    [Document] => -
    [Id] => 10
    [Is_Received] => 0
    [Is_Personal_Submission] => 1
)
```

UPDATE:

Your code should look something like

```
<?php 
    foreach($appreq as $row => $data): 
    // table name print
    // table headers print
        foreach ($data as $key => $values) :
            //print row content by calling $values['Is_Received'], $values['Name'], ...
        endforeach;
    endforeach
?>
```

I hope this answers your question.
Please, let me know if there is anything else unclear.

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php 
    foreach($appreq as $row => $value) : ?>

    <table style="text-align: left; width: 50%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th width='10' style="text-align:center;">Received</th>
            <th scope="col">Requirement</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <h5><strong><?= $ancillarypermit[$row]->permit->Name ?></strong></h5>
        <?php 
            foreach ($value as $key => $values) :
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td width='150' style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 3px'>
                        <?php 
                        echo CheckboxX::widget([
                            'name'=>'s_1', 
                            'value'=>$values['Is_Received'], 
                            // 'readonly'=>true, 
                            'pluginOptions'=>['threeState'=>false]
                        ]);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?= $values['Name']  ?> </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: You posted this answer faster, i deleted my one :)

Comment: Thanks that explains why I get the Names right away when I use: $data[0]['Name']. But before I get to the data, I need to segregate the array on the first [0] => Array, because it represents each table. so the first [0] => Array is table 1 and [1] => Array is table 2. Please check my updated question, I added an image for the expected table result, thanks

Comment: @wolfQueen I hope this will answer your question. Please let me know if there is anything else. You can see below UPDATE

Comment: @MartinDimitrov I tried doing what u suggested, unfortunately I get all of the data in one table only.. I updated my question and added an image of the result. I also added my whole code for the table.thank you very much

Comment: @wolfQueen. I cannot write you the code at this moment, but please not in the above example, you have things to put between the 2 `for`. Put the new tables headers there.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov great, with your help I was able to divide the $appreq array per table, but the problem now is at the table title, $ancillarypermit, it iterates along with the $appreq. I tried to put it somewhere else but im getting other results, maybe you can do the trick again, I updated the question with an image, thanks again

Comment: @wolfQueen can you show me the `$ancillarypermi` array? If you can edit the question to show the table array, I can tell you how to handle it.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov cool thanks! I have added an image in the question for the `$ancillarypermit` array. fyi: the array contains raw data and I display the name of the permit(local clearance, etc) from its value: `Permit=>1` that's why I have the `$data->permit->Name` as seen in the table.

Comment: @wolfQueen I have edited my answer. I am not quite sure if it will work though, as I am not 100% sure how does the structure look. If it doesn't, I suggest switch to chat, so we do not spam here and I will look into it and help you and later edit the answer with the correct final information.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov it worked like a charm!! thanks for all of your help! I will further study this to be more familiarized how arrays works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @wolfQueen No worries :) Is there something you want me to explain here? If anything is unclear, I will explain it to you.